# How to setup correct type in typescript abstract class?

Tags: typescript

I have problem with setting correct type in abstract class. I would like to do something like this:

```
abstract class AbstractMap<TTile extends AbstractTile> {
  public readonly fields: TTile[];

  constructor() {
    this.fields = [this.createTile(0,0), this.createTile(0,1)];
  }

  protected abstract createTile(x: number, y: number): TTile;
}

abstract class AbstractTile {
  protected abstract readonly map: AbstractMap<this>;

  protected constructor(public readonly x: number, public readonly y: number) {
  }

  public get neighbors(): this[] {
    return this.map.fields.filter(f => f);
  }
}

class ServerMap extends AbstractMap<ServerTile> {
  protected createTile(x: number, y: number): ServerTile {
    return new ServerTile(x, y, this);
  }
}

class ServerTile extends AbstractTile {
  protected readonly map: ServerMap;

  constructor(x: number, y: number, map: ServerMap) {
    super(x, y);
    this.map = map;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get *ServerMap* type on `ServerTile.map` property, but all the time I have an error:

```
   Type 'ServerMap' is not assignable to type 'AbstractMap<this>'.
     Types of property 'fields' are incompatible.
       Type 'ServerTile[]' is not assignable to type 'this[]'.
         Type 'ServerTile' is not assignable to type 'this'.
           'ServerTile' is assignable to the constraint of type 'this', but 'this' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'ServerTile'.
```

I tried to set `AbstractMap<AbstractTile>` instead of `AbstractMap<this>` in `AbstractTile` class but then I need to set `AbstractTile[]` return type on `AbstractTile.neighbors` function.

Comment: The polymorphic `this` type is hard to use without type assertions inside class implementations, because it has to apply to *every possible* subtype of the class. But someone can write `class Foo extends ServerTile { p = "x" }; new Foo(1, 2, new ServerMap()).neighbors[0].p.toUpperCase();` to get a runtime error, showing that `this` isn't safe.  In cases like this, direct F-bounded polymorphism is often easier to implement... as in [this version of your example](https://tsplay.dev/wOAE6m). Does that fully address the question? If so I will write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works and now i understand why this were not ok. It's a little problematic in my case because it's simplified version of code to reproduce error, but i can live with that becouse of strict typing.

Comment: You could always just [assert your way out of the error](https://tsplay.dev/w17jYm) as long as you're aware of the possible problems.  I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) type is an implicitly [F-bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification) type.  It acts like a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the current type.  And like generics, it is easier to specify the type argument than it is to write code that treats it as an unresolved parameter.  Inside the class bodies of `AbstractTile` and its descendant classes, we only know that `this` will be *some* subtype of the current class.  But we don't know which one.  And that means a lot of code you write could turn out to be technically unsafe in the presence of unanticipated subclasses.  For example, with your code, someone could write:

```
class Oops extends ServerTile { prop = "oops" }

const oopses = new Oops(1, 2, new ServerMap()).neighbors;
// const oopses: Oops[]
```

The compiler believes that `oopses` is of type `Oops[]` because that's the supposed type of `neighbors`.  But your implementation of `ServerMap` doesn't work that way, and so you get a runtime error if you continue:

```
oopses.forEach(o => o.prop.toUpperCase()) // compiles okay, but
//  RUNTIME ERROR! o.prop is undefined
```

So the error message the compiler gives you, that `'ServerTile' is assignable to the constraint of type 'this', but 'this' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'ServerTile'` is telling you exactly what the problem is.

---

Of course you might decide that such things are unlikely to happen and you want to just use a `this` type anyway.  That is your prerogative, and you can just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to the compiler that it isn't a problem:

```
class ServerTile extends AbstractTile {
  protected readonly map: AbstractMap<this>;
  constructor(x: number, y: number, map: ServerMap) {
    super(x, y);
    // assert
    this.map = map as AbstractMap<AbstractTile> as AbstractMap<this>;
  }
}
```

This suppresses the compiler error, and it's now your responsibility to make sure that `ServerMap` behaves like `AbstractMap<this>` for all the `this` types you will encounter.

---

If you really care about trying to write this in a more verifiably type-safe way, you can trade the implicit F-bounded type parameter `this` type for an *explicit* F-bounded type parameter `T`.  Something of the form `T extends F<T>`.  In your case that's `class AbstractTile<T extends AbstractTile<T>>`:

```
abstract class AbstractMap<T extends AbstractTile<T>> {
  public readonly fields: T[];

  constructor() {
    this.fields = [this.createTile(0, 0), this.createTile(0, 1)];
  }

  protected abstract createTile(x: number, y: number): T;
}

abstract class AbstractTile<T extends AbstractTile<T>> {
  protected abstract readonly map: AbstractMap<T>;

  protected constructor(public readonly x: number, public readonly y: number) {
  }

  public get neighbors(): T[] {
    return this.map.fields.filter(f => f);
  }
}
```

And now you can write `ServerMap` and `ServerTile` as follows:

```
class ServerMap extends AbstractMap<ServerTile> {
  protected createTile(x: number, y: number): ServerTile {
    return new ServerTile(x, y, this);
  }
}

class ServerTile extends AbstractTile<ServerTile> {
  protected readonly map: ServerMap;

  constructor(x: number, y: number, map: ServerMap) {
    super(x, y);
    this.map = map;
  }
}
```

All of that compiles as desired.  And the failure mode from before is no longer possible, because now the `neighbors` property is of type `ServerTile[]` and not of type `Oops[]`:

```
class Oops extends ServerTile { prop = "oops" }

const oopses = new Oops(1, 2, new ServerMap()).neighbors;
// const oopses: ServerTile[]
```

So if you try to reference the `prop` property of `oopses[0]`, the compiler will complain.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgIJRQQBOALgJoD2ArrQOogCeA8q-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-QVyyQKVvyrf59IEqkYcxYNluJEY9HWhjMOPQndD2s1IYvfMccEcUTrQ28CIfHQKauxEofzG6ig-NlvFFK9GcRn9hQFzkGdxFHK1lKmsZqQ6kHVTVtV1fVaENatdFNM8PCbWhrVte1HTaF0jHdMpPQ6b14P9Kkx1EPGVPTaN6PjUmNEfJi8N1tiabOAslnh0YRf-aW-1lIDt3rcCsUtA2W3bb2Vh7FG+0aW3gUDDwneTli3c2+9CbziB9oVrmA8l3lAOdtSOcd4TeZZT8ZeR1GkYA28mNJB6EMg-zYJRzPciNlCuntTGyPtwSnYs4n3ZL1i6q6bjeP4h28mE1dTNsLplIs2SFKUtta9oUkNK01XdI1zHwq3myzNPkYrM64QdiAA)